# Data saving in Fluentd or Fluentbit?

Tags: docker, fluentd

Good morning people!
I would like to know, please, the following:
Does [fluentd](https://docs.fluentd.org/) save Data when the system shuts down, or when there is no internet?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depend all from your configuation.

You can use, for example, a [buffer](https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/buffer-section) block, available on file or in memory, to bufferize your data.

You can also use, in some output plugin, the [secondary_file](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/secondary_file) that allow you a fail-over write on disk.

So, yes fluentd can save data but all depend from your configuration